# Android Architecture sample unit testing live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

```
@Test
fun sendResultToUI() {

    val foo = MutableLiveData<Resource<User>>()
    val bar = MutableLiveData<Resource<User>>()
    `when`(userRepository.loadUser("foo")).thenReturn(foo)
    `when`(userRepository.loadUser("bar")).thenReturn(bar)
    val observer = mock<Observer<Resource<User>>>()
    userViewModel.user.observeForever(observer) //Create foo and bar, observe user live data

    userViewModel.setLogin("foo")
    verify(observer, never()).onChanged(any()) //Make sure that setting login to foo did not touch vm.user?

    /*val fooUser = TestUtil.createUser("foo")
    val fooValue = Resource.success(fooUser)
    foo.value = fooValue
    verify(observer).onChanged(fooValue)
    reset(observer)

    val barUser = TestUtil.createUser("bar")
    val barValue = Resource.success(barUser)
    bar.value = barValue
    userViewModel.setLogin("bar")
    verify(observer).onChanged(barValue)*/
}
```

Can anyone please explain wtf this line: `verify(observer, never()).onChanged(any())` is doing in Google's [GithubBrowser](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) sample? I just don't understand it, calling `setLogin()` *fires* the observer so how the hell can we verify that `onChanged()` was never called when we specifically triggered it on the previous line!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calling setLogin() fires the observer

No, calling `setLogin` just return your a `foo` `LiveData`, the underlying value is not updated yet until you set it (`foo.value = fooValue`). So this line tests `onChange` is not called if no value received.

Comment: Thanks @jaychang0917, so calling `setLogin` normally triggers the `user` live data to call `userRepository.loadUser(login)`, but we override that with ``when`(userRepository.loadUser("foo")).thenReturn(foo)`. But the user live data switchmap is still triggered, does this not mean the `observer` in the test was changed?

Comment: ya, the `switchmap` is triggered, but the `userRepository` is a mocked object, so `loadUser` will not set the value of underlying `LiveData`, so `onChange` is not going to be called.

Comment: Okay thank you I think it makes sense! So basically it is confirming that `setLogin` did nothing except for loading a mocked foo. And in the next step it makes sure that setting a value on that mocked foo *is* observed. I think `sendResultToUI` is a very confusing name for this test :)